# MongoDB match filters with grouping and get total count

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, data-manipulation

My sample data:

```
{
    "_id": "random_id_1",
    "priority": "P1",
    "owners": ["user-1", "user-2"],
},
{
    "_id": "random_id_2",
    "priority": "P1",
    "owners": ["user-1", "user-2"],
},
{
    "_id": "random_id_3",
    "priority": "P2",
    "owners": ["user-1", "user-2"],
},
```

I want to run an aggregation pipeline on the data involving match filters and grouping, also I want to limit the number of groups returned as well as the number of items in each group.
Essentially, if `limit=2, limit_per_group=1, group_by=owner, priority=P1`, I want the following results:

```
[
  {
     "data": [
       {
          "group_key": "user-1",
          "total_items_in_group": 2,
          "limited_items": [
             {
                 "_id": "random_id_1",
                 "priority": "P1",
                 "owners": ["user-1", "user-2"],
             },
          ],
       },
       {
          "group_key": "user-2",
          "total_items_in_group": 2,
          "limited_items": [
             {
                 "_id": "random_id_1",
                 "priority": "P1",
                 "owners": ["user-1", "user-2"],
             },
          ],
       },
     ]
  },
  {
     "metadata": {
        "total_items_matched": 2,
        "total_groups": 2
     }
  },
]
```

Need some help on how to write an aggregation pipeline to get the required result.
My current query is as follows:

```
{
    "$match": {
      "priority": "P1"
    }
  },
  {
    "$facet": {
      "data": [
        {
          $addFields: {
            "group_by_owners": "$owners"
          }
        },
        {
          $unwind: "$group_by_owners"
        },
        {
          $group: {
            "_id": "$group_by_owners",
            "total_items_in_group": {
              $sum: 1
            },
            "items": {
              $push: "$$ROOT"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $sort: {
            "total": -1
          }
        },
        {
          $unset: "items.group_by_owners"
        },
        {
          $project: {
            "_id": 1,
            "total_items_in_group": 1,
            "limited_items": {
              $slice: [
                "$items",
                1
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "$limit": 2
        }
      ],
      "metadata": [
        {
          $count: "total_items_matched"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

[Mongo playground link](https://mongoplayground.net/p/7_iGWgF4NLF)
I am unable to calculate the **total number of groups**.

Comment: what is the **total number of groups** => `total_groups`?  how it will calculate?

Comment: Number of groups formed after filtering. Essentially, how many unique values of `owners` are there among all the filtered documents.

Answer (score 0):

add new stage of `$addfields` at the end of pipeline

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "priority": "P1"
    }
  },
  {
    "$facet": {
      "data": [
        {
          $addFields: {
            "group_by_owners": "$owners"
          }
        },
        {
          $unwind: "$group_by_owners"
        },
        {
          $group: {
            "_id": "$group_by_owners",
            "total_items_in_group": {
              $sum: 1
            },
            "items": {
              $push: "$$ROOT"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $sort: {
            "total": -1
          }
        },
        {
          $unset: "items.group_by_owners"
        },
        {
          $project: {
            "_id": 0,
            "group_key": "$_id",
            "total_items_in_group": 1,
            "limited_items": {
              $slice: [
                "$items",
                1
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "$limit": 2
        }
      ],
      "metadata": [
        {
          $count: "total_items_matched",
          
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "metadata.total_groups": {
        "$size": "$data"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

https://mongoplayground.net/p/y5a0jvr6fxI

Comment: This solution will give the wrong output as `$size: $data` in the end will give the number of groups after the limit operation has been applied. So, if I change it to `$limit: 1`, then the  value of `total_groups` will be 1 which is wrong.